# Storing remote virtual address in DWORD?

Tags: c++11, pointers, 64-bit, virtual-address-space, dword

I need to get the RVA of a specific function in a dll and then add that RVA to the base loading address of the dll to find the function in the remote processes memory. However I need to pass this memory address in a buffer to a thread that will be created in the remote process. So I was wondering whether or not I should pass this as a DWORD representation of the address. I'm on 64 bit Windows, so if so should it be DWORD_PTR, DWORD64, etc? Or can I still just pass it as a pointer which wouldn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do brief investigation. We will refer to [spec](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwuO-RwO3NAhUqGZoKHVU3AtYQFggqMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fe%2Fb%2Fa%2Feba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45%2Fpecoff.doc&usg=AFQjCNHwqIN-m3oOEvNsox3CLrGBp8pZzQ&sig2=dXbw2z0WYxwUtgWabPtCQg&bvm=bv.126993452,d.bGs). Look at `SizeOfImage` field in optional header:

> Size, in bytes, of image, including all headers; must be a multiple of
>   Section Alignment.

Actually this is the size of mapped image and it is 4-byte integer both for PE32 and PE32+ formats. As consequence all relative addresses inside PE are always fit into 32-bit integer. Also the most of RVA fields in PE structures are declared as `DWORD`, that IMO is a good hint.

To top it off: you can store RVA in `DWORD` both on 32-bit or 64-bit system.